# AsciiDocs docdir returns wrong path

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm working on a branch 'test' that publishes an HTML and PDF file to branch 'test-publish'.
My docdir in {docdir}/path/to/image.png does not seem to be working. That is, the images folder is inside of the 'test-publish' branch, but docdir doesn't recognize that and my images are not being rendered. It prints some random characters then '/path/to/images.png'. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that AsciiDocs docdir only works locally, not when running on an agent. I passed in another argument to take its place, and that worked.